# Update in one single Oracle Query

Tags: oracle11g, outer-join, insert-update, insert-into

I tried to write the one single code in Oracle database but I couldn’t merge it to one single query and When I run the code initially I’m getting “ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error. I also try to use FOR LOOP , CASE statement  but still it did not work. Can you please let me know  how  do I merge  query in one single code  ?

Requirements 
Create Column CIDO on  DTW and Insert data from V to DTW the following criteria must meet 
CIDO= CID
As part of the join I have to use left join to Q table on CID from V   and SID from Q 
Then need to update CID filed in DTW with CFCID in Q Where CCode from V = MX00

I wrote :

```
Alter table DTW add CIDO  -- added column 


Select  V.CID from  V,Q  where  V.CID=Q.SID 
Insert into DTW (CIDO)
Select V.CID from  V 
Left outer join Q  on V.CID = Q.SID 

Update DTW
Set CIDO = (select V.CID from V, Q
Where V.CID=Q.CFCID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't say how you're running this, so I'm assuming sqlplus. You have 4 different commands there. At the command line you'll need to run each one and put a ; at the end of each.

```
-- Pretty sure your syntax is wrong here. What's the datatype of CIDO?
Alter table DTW add CIDO;

-- This will just display a list of CIDs, not sure if that's what you want.
Select  V.CID from  V,Q  where  V.CID=Q.SID;

-- This will insert one or more rows from V and Q
Insert into DTW (CIDO)
Select V.CID from  V 
Left outer join Q  on V.CID = Q.SID;

-- This will update all the rows in DTW to the same value, which is probably not what
-- you want. Also, if there's more than one row in this subquery, it will raise an error.
Update DTW
Set CIDO = (select V.CID from V, Q
Where V.CID=Q.CFCID);
```